# Bigquery SSL error while doing streaming insert api call

Tags: google-bigquery, google-api-java-client

We are using bigquery streaming api to insert entries. Off late we are getting lots of SSL exceptions. Please let me know how to handle these?

I came across this StackOverflow ticket [How to handle Bigquery Remote host closed connection during handshake exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24638936/how-to-handle-bigquery-remote-host-closed-connection-during-handshake-exception) but nobody posed any clue to that. Hence I am rasing the issue again.

We are using bigquery api java client v2-rev188-1.19.1

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:946) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1312) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1339) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1323) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:563) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1091) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:250) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:77) ~[google-http-client-1.19.0.jar:1.19.0]
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:965) ~[google-http-client-1.19.0.jar:1.19.0]
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.batch.BatchRequest.execute(BatchRequest.java:241) ~[google-api-client-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.livestream.analytics.datastorage.worker.InsertApiActor$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$4.apply(InsertApiActor.scala:131) ~[analytics-data-storage-worker_2.11-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
    at com.livestream.analytics.datastorage.worker.InsertApiActor$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$4.apply(InsertApiActor.scala:118) ~[analytics-data-storage-worker_2.11-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
    at com.livestream.analytics.common.store.bigquery.api.BigQueryApi$.withSyncClient(BigQueryApi.scala:71) ~[analytics-common_2.11-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
    at com.livestream.analytics.datastorage.worker.InsertApiActor$$anonfun$2.apply$mcV$sp(InsertApiActor.scala:118) ~[analytics-data-storage-worker_2.11-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
    at com.livestream.analytics.datastorage.worker.InsertApiActor$$anonfun$2.apply(InsertApiActor.scala:115) ~[analytics-data-storage-worker_2.11-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
    at com.livestream.analytics.datastorage.worker.InsertApiActor$$anonfun$2.apply(InsertApiActor.scala:115) ~[analytics-data-storage-worker_2.11-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
    at com.livestream.analytics.common.monitoring.Timer.time(Timer.scala:15) ~[analytics-common_2.11-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
    at com.livestream.analytics.datastorage.worker.InsertApiActor.com$livestream$analytics$datastorage$worker$InsertApiActor$$insertDataRowsToBigQueryTable(InsertApiActor.scala:115) [analytics-data-storage-worker_2.11-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
    at com.livestream.analytics.datastorage.worker.InsertApiActor$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(InsertApiActor.scala:80) [analytics-data-storage-worker_2.11-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
    at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:465) [akka-actor_2.11-2.3.9.jar:na]
    at com.livestream.analytics.datastorage.worker.InsertApiActor.aroundReceive(InsertApiActor.scala:54) [analytics-data-storage-worker_2.11-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:516) [akka-actor_2.11-2.3.9.jar:na]
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:487) [akka-actor_2.11-2.3.9.jar:na]
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:254) [akka-actor_2.11-2.3.9.jar:na]
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:221) [akka-actor_2.11-2.3.9.jar:na]
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:231) [akka-actor_2.11-2.3.9.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260) [scala-library-2.11.5.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339) [scala-library-2.11.5.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979) [scala-library-2.11.5.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107) [scala-library-2.11.5.jar:na]
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:482) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:927) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    ... 30 common frames omitted
```